# CSS sprite not working on Chrome mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, css-sprites

HTML:

```
<span class="activity-2">&nbsp;</span>
```

CSS:

```
.activity-2 {
    background-position: 0 -80px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/E5Jr2Tv.png);
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    text-indent: -1000em;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mqkofuq/

The background image displays correctly on every desktop / mobile browser I've tested, except from Chrome mobile. Why??

Answer (score 0):

try adding preserveAspectRatio="none" to your class

Comment: That's for SVGs only?

Comment: my bad i misread and tought you used .svg, your problem is mostlikely the size of your image 40*4760. mobile browsers can not handle images that are that big even if you only show a small part of the image

Comment: Interesting to know. I tried opening the image by typing the url directly and it works. Is there a limit to the size of an background image?

Comment: i think images cause problems on phones  because of the time it takes to load them.So you could try to use a site like https://tinypng.com/ they remove uneeded information from the .ong file